# Python add windowsPath to sys.path

Tags: python, python-import, pythonpath, python-importlib

I need to dynamically add packages which are created on the fly to my `sys.path`. I have a `some.py` file holding a method `that` in the directory `media\TEMP`:

This code works:

```
sys.path.append("""C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\testtool\\media\\TEMP""")
```

this results in:

```
[
...
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\\testTool\\venv', 
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\\testTool\\venv\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\\testTool\\media\\TEMP'
]
```

and `importlib.import_module(f"{some}.{that}")` works. But this does not work:

```
sys.path.append(Path.cwd().parent.joinpath("media", "TEMP"))
```

this results in:

```
[
... 
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\\testTool\\venv', 
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\tools\\\testTool\\venv\\lib\\site-packages', 
WindowsPath('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/tools/testTool/media/TEMP'
]
```

and this fails with a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Can't a windows path be in the `sys.path`? I also tried `Path.resolve()` with no success.

Comment: Call `str()` on the `WindowsPath`.

Comment: Please post it as answer so I can accept it in my stupidity.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put `pathlib.Path` objects (including `WindowsPath`) in `sys.path`, only plain strings.

In other words, you'll need to call `str(...)` on them:

```
sys.path.append(str(Path.cwd().parent.joinpath("media", "TEMP")))
```